# Ubuntu Suddenly Won't Load

Tags: 12.04, grub2, windows

I was using the computer and I went back to Windows and it launched in start-up repair. Now when I try to start Ubuntu this screen comes up that says something about grub files and talks about giving some command. Then it has `grub>` and a blinking cursor.

I honestly don't know how to get rid of it and I would just uninstall and reinstall Ubuntu but I don't want to lose my files which I hadn't backed up. Help?

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to reinstall Ubuntu, only reinstall Grub. You can boot from a LiveCD of Ubuntu and try reinstall it:

Open the live version. Open the terminal and run `sudo fdisk -l` to see where Linux is installed.

Run `sudo mount /dev/sdaX /mnt` where `X` is the number you have found Linux word in.

Run `sudo grub-install --root-directory=/mnt /dev/sda` to install grub.

Run `sudo update-grub` to update grub.

Reboot.

More information on reinstalling grub:

- [How do I reinstall grub2?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/83037/how-do-i-reinstall-grub2)

Comment: ... and don't let Windows "repair" your computer again ;)

Comment: Do I have to buy a livecd?

Comment: No. You can download it for free in Ubuntu.com Follow this link: http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop

Answer (score 0):

Here's a method that doesn't require you to run a large number of commands.

Try the following:

1. Boot with Ubuntu latest version LiveCD
2. When you get to the Live Desktop, open the terminal ( [What is a terminal and how do I open and use it?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/38162/what-is-the-terminal) ) and type these commands:

   - `sudo grub-install /dev/sda`
   - `sudo update-grub`

You are done. Reboot the machine and grub is installed to hard disk MBR.