# How can I fix dual boot with Ubuntu after installing Manjaro alongside it?

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, bootloader

I installed Manjaro alongside Ubuntu and now it boots straight into Manjaro without the option of loading Ubuntu. How can I fix this? I'm not wanting to reinstall the grub.

Comment: This is about Manjaro, not Ubuntu.

Comment: Please run the [Boot Repair utility](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair) and select the "Create BootInfo Summary" option. (*DO NOT* click "Recommended Repair," at least not yet!) When asked whether to upload the report, click "Yes," and then post the URL provided here. This will give us more details about your configuration, which is required to base an answer on more than guesswork.

Comment: @mikewhatever, I disagree; it's about a dual-boot scenario that involves both OSes. I see questions like this all the time with "Windows" in place of "Manjaro," and nobody bats an eye about their acceptability on this site.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I reinstall grub2?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/83037/how-do-i-reinstall-grub2)

Comment: This isn't about reinstalling grub

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix thanks :) hope it doesn't get closed

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I repair grub? (How to get Ubuntu back after installing Windows?)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/88384/how-can-i-repair-grub-how-to-get-ubuntu-back-after-installing-windows)

Comment: GRUB actually didn't need repairing or reinstalling. The menu just wasn't coming up, so config needed editing

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to two of you.  I found that if I hold <kbd>c</kbd> during startup the menu will appear.  There's an edit to the grub file to make it happen automatically.

For permanent change edit:

```
/etc/default/grub
```

place a `#` symbol at the start of line `GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT=0`.

Save changes and run:

```
sudo update-grub
```